# A/C only blowing in half the house

Tags: hvac

For about 18 hours yesterday, no A/C was blowing from any of the vents in the front half of the house.  The back half of the house was working fine.  All of the sudden, the air started flowing to the front of the house.  What would cause that type of issue?

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include clear, focused pictures of your furnace/air handler, that might help people help you diagnose the issue. It will allow those who know what they're looking at to determine what kind of equipment you have and point out areas to check into.

Answer (score 1):

Two different air handlers, one of which shut down.

Or a zone damper on a single air handler which stuck.